# Is there a way in Webpack to extract imported CSS into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, sass

This is my folder structure:

```
src/yolo/block.js
src/yolo/editor.scss
src/yolo/style.scss
```

This is an excerpt of my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync('src/**/block.js'),
  output: { path: 'dist' },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
  ...
}
```

This is what the js file looks like:

### block.js

```
import './editor.scss'
import './style.scss'
```

I expect the output to be:

```
dist/yolo/block.js -> es5
dist/yolo/editor.css
dist/yolo/style.css
```

But instead I get:

```
dist/yolo/block.js
dist/yolo/block.css
```

Answer (score 0):

What Webpack does here is to compile all CSS and JS dependencies in 2 files because they are required/imported in the block.js. Importing a file means your code needs them, it would be wrong not to package them with Webpack.

If you want Webpack to compile different CSS/JS in different files you have to create another JS file that will include only one CSS file and remove the appropriate import from block.js.